# Products without a sale in the order table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to come up with a list of products without a sale, yet both tables are really long. At first my SQL I've been using but receiving timeout:"

```
SELECT products.product_id
FROM products
LEFT JOIN order_items USING (product_id)
WHERE order_items.product_id IS NULL
```

by using explain function before select:

```
Table       | Rows
Products    | 840,949
Order_Items | 688,499
```

It seems I'm not being efficient. Do you guys have any idea how to be more effective?
Result I would like to achieve:

```
Product_ID
2323432
4565435
3453457
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried

```
SELECT products.product_id
FROM products
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 'x'
FROM order_items where 
order_items.product_id = products.product_id)
```

But still can't process the query, taking too long

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your exists query is fine, though I would write it as:

```sql
SELECT p.product_id
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_items oi WHERE oi.product_id = p.product_id);
```

As for performance, you may add the following index on the `order_items` table to speed things up:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON order_items (product_id);
```

This index, if used, would allow very rapid lookup of a given `product_id` in the `order_items` table.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `join` is exploding. To test for that, try this subquery based approach.

```
select p.product_id
from (select distinct product_id from products) p
left join (select distinct product_id from order_items) o 
where o.product_id is null;
```